# order by first occurence of returned results

Tags: sql

I have two tables and want to get technology_tag from table b based on reference id from table a:

```
select b.dbid, b.technology_tag 
from tblConnect a, tblSites b 
where a.Site_DBID = 2 
and a.Related_Site_DBID = 1 
and (b.dbid = a.bsc_tag_dbid or b.dbid = a.related_bsc_dbid or b.dbid = a.related_msc_dbid)
```

What I want to have here is to order the returned rows based on first occurrence (in where clause)

```
1st- b.dbid = a.bsc_tag_dbid  
2cnd- b.dbid = a.related_bsc_dbid 
3rd- b.dbid = a.related_msc_dbid
```

Does anyone has a clue how to do that?

Comment: I've formatted your code so there's a chance others can read it. You should do this yourself in future - use the code button `{}` to mark up code, but also try not to have too much appearing on a single line. A format such as the above (it's not the only possible way to do this) makes it easier for everyone (yourself included in 6 months time) to find the separate clauses of the query.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should switch to using actual JOIN clauses when performing joins. That said, this ORDER BY clause should do what you want:

```
SELECT
    B.dbid,
    B.technology_tag
FROM tblConnect A
INNER JOIN tblSites B ON
    B.dbid IN (A.bsc_tag_dbid, A.related_bsc_dbid, A.related_msc_dbid)
WHERE
    A.Site_DBID = 2 AND
    A.Related_Site_DBID = 1
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN B.dbid = A.bsc_tag_dbid THEN 1
        WHEN B.dbid = A.related_bsc_dbid THEN 2
        WHEN B.dbid = A.related_msc_dbid THEN 3
        ELSE 4   -- Not really necessary, but I always use an ELSE when I use CASE
    END
```

Comment: but the query now takes much time to retrieve the records, do you have any idea?

Comment: First, I would change the query to use proper JOIN syntax. Then make sure that your tables are properly indexed. Depending on the specific RDBMS that you're using it may include tools for analyzing your query to see where it's taking the most time. You could also change the OR statements into a single IN statement: `B.dbid IN (A.bsc_tag_dbid, A.related_bsc_dbid, A.related_msc_dbid)`

Comment: you are right (i forget to put index on that A table), thanks again > one last question: you were talking about JOIN syntax: can you please rephrase the who query to see how it should looks like using JOIN

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the full query with the JOIN syntax